# SQL Help. Trying to achive a certain result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I don't think this will be possible, but then I'm no SQL guru so I'd like to make sure. We're using SQL Server 2012.

We have a table structure like this:

```
 Id | LastChanged | TypeId  
 1 | 01/01/2014 | 1  
 1 | 02/02/2014 | 1  
 2 | 03/03/2014 | 1  
 2 | 04/04/2014 | 1  
 3 | 01/01/2014 | 1  
 3 | 02/02/2014 | 1  
 4 | 02/02/2014 | 2  
 4 | 03/03/2014 | 2
```

-Id and LastChanged is the primary key.
-LastChanged is a DateTime data type.
-The reason for this setup is to create a history of changes.

The "active" record would be the one with the most recent date. If I were to get the "active" record I would do this:

```
 SELECT TOP 1  Id, LastChanged, TypeId  
 WHERE   Id = 1  
 ORDER BY LastChanged desc
```

The result of the above query being:

> 1 | 02/02/2014 | 1

The result set I'm trying to achive is to get the "active" records by TypeId:

> 1 | 02/02/2014 | 1
>   2 | 04/04/2014 | 1
>   3 | 02/02/2014 | 1

Comment: What you mean by *Active Record* ??

Comment: Have you tried using MAX(LastChanged)?  That would return the record with the most recent activity.

Comment: I would determine max(LastChanged ) group by id.

Comment: I was hoping I had explained that. :( I'll try again. The "active" record is the only one the user can see and update. Once an "update" occours, a new record is actually inserted with a timestamp and would become the "active" record since it has the latest date.

Comment: "The result set I'm trying to achive is to get the "active" records by TypeId" But your example shows the active record by Id, not TypeId. And it's missing an entry for Id = 4.

Comment: This is where it's confusing. The PK is Id AND LastChanged. There can be multiple Id's that are the same. And yes, Id=4 shouldn't be in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER` to get your last active records. I guess you want to filter by `TypeID`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LastChanged DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
    WHERE  TypeID = @TypeID
)
SELECT Id, LastChanged, TypeId  
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7b25/3/0

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be a simpler solution. to achieve the highest change date for each Id

```
SELECT 
 Id
,MAX(LastChanged)
,TypeId  
FROM YourTable

GROUP BY 
 Id
,TypeId
```

if you only want the result set to show the Type Id with the number of 1 then

```
SELECT 
 Id
,MAX(LastChanged)
,TypeId  
FROM YourTable

WHERE TypeId = 1

GROUP BY 
 Id
,TypeId
```

Comment: But you need to add, in possibly an outer clause, where changed=max_changed. I think it is the best solution. However, it is just not complete as it is.

Comment: the query gets the highest changed In the select clause. the max(lastchanged) will only returned the highest values for each Id and TypeId as defined in the Group By Clause